# Oracle SQL partition selection in Linq-To-Entities

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I'm trying to transpose this Oracle SQL query in EF using Linq-To-Entities:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable PARTITION(p1);
```

Problem is, how could I translate the partition selection ? I'm pretty sure there is no simple and easy way to do it, but I really need to select a single partition somehow.

I need to say, I did not try anything since I really don't know where to start.

Any clue ?

Comment: Instead of using the partition notation, why don't you switch to using a where clause that matches with the column you partitioned on? E.g. if you have a list partitioned table and the partition you are interested in matches to values of col1 = 1, then your query would become `select * from mytable where col1 = 1;`. The where clause can drive which partition(s) are used, and Oracle can do partition pruning to only look at the partition(s) it needs to.

Comment: Good point, but I should not know on which clause the partition were made of. I just know the name of the partition, that's why I just cant get around the partition selection.

Comment: This is great example that you need to think about architecture ahead. there are always conflict between DBA/Coder. DBA thinks about DB performance. Coder needs to be able to utilize the tools at hand. EF has limitations and not good for high performance coding. If you have some CRUD - its ok. You can always use `DbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand` for raw sql.

Comment: Ok I see, that's what I thought to be honnest. Well, thanks anyway.